# special permissions set to deny on new subfolders of a folder I own with Full Control

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, cygwin, rsnapshot

I have rsnapshot 1.3.1 installed under cygwin64 (setup 2.870, dll 1.7.35) on win2012r2, all the latest as of today.

I configured it to take a single file, current.7z, and make a rotating backup of it.  I have sync_first set to 1.

When I run `rsnapshot sync && rsnapshot hourly` from a cygwin terminal running as the local admin it completes with no errors, and no complaints in verbose-level-5 output.

However, the snapshot it produces isn't accessible via windows explorer: I can burrow in as far as c:\backups.snapshots\hourly.x\cygdrive without problem, but double-clicking the "c" folder in there gives me:

> You don't currently have permission to access this folder.
>
> Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder.

So I click Continue (I'm logged in as local admin, remember) and it says:

> You have been denied permission to access this folder.
>
> To gain access to this folder you will need to use the security tab.

So I go to the security tab for "c" (which the error popup links to), and find that the only "deny" entry for any of the users listed is for Administrator, for "special permissions," and it's grey, and it won't let me set it to Allow when I try editing.  Administrator otherwise has Full Control and all other things set to Allow.

How can I fix this?

1. what special permission are they talking about here that would override my ability to browse?

   - OK, the answer to this is that, despite Full Control and List Folder Contents being Allow, apparently Special Permissions can contain exactly those in its Deny.  I thought they only included other things that were not listed in the normal view.
2. more importantly, why does rsnapshot produce directories with these special permissions set to deny?

### Things I've Tried

1. my conf has `./` as the end of the backup line.  tried making it something like `current/`.  it moves the backup but same result.
2. my conf has `cmd_cp` uncommented despite the warning in the comments above it, because with it commented, rsnapshot would fail with `ERROR: rsync_cleanup_after_native_cp_al() only works on directories`: this is true both if I make the backup line point to the directory current.7z is in (with the proper `/` at the end as the docs say), or directly at current.7z; furthermore, despite this error at the end of the rsnapshot run, it does actually produce a backup, but again, with the same permissions errors
3. deleting the snapshot dirs to try over--won't let me delete them (doesn't complain, but doesn't delete either, doing shift-delete from win explorer)
4. changing permissions on every directory up the hierarchy to Full Control for local admin
5. going to advanced editing on hourly.x, showing all permissions, having everything checked for Allow, replacing permissions on this folder and on all subfolders and files.  hooray, I can access it finally, but I'd like to be able to view any backup without first having this runaround.
6. doing the above on C:\backups, then deleting the snapshots dirs and starting again.  it still makes new dirs with these special permissions denied, despite admins group ownership of the parent and specific Full Control and all special permissions given to local admin, with inheritance enabled.  what does that mean, if not that the subfolders and files should, well, inherit the permissions set on the parent?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this line in the output, which wasn't marked as an error like the one I was getting when cmd_cp was commented out:

```
Lchown module not found
```

Apparently I need Lchown for rsnapshot to correctly set permissions.  But cygwin doesn't seem to have it...

I guess before accessing a backup I'll have to reset perms either via chmod or via Windows security tab.  Unfortunate.

Comment: A search on that message brings up http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/rsnapshot-require-lchown-516423/.  Have you tried suggestions such as those?

Comment: Yes but even with mwingw-gcc-core installed, the perl line complains about a bunch of further modules breaking.  I was hoping there was a drop-in fix, as I don't have time to debug Lchown not compiling on cygwin.

Comment: I'd try asking on the Cygwin mailing list.